# Como modifico la versión de python instalada?

Tags: python

tengo la versión 3.10.2 de python pero si pongo en el cmd `python --version` me sale que tengo la 3.8.8, tampoco me sale en el panel de control para desinstalarla, se puede hacer que la 3.10.2 sea la global?

Comment: Revisa PATH de sistema de las variables de entorno. Deben estar solo las referencias a la versión que necesitas, 3.10 en este caso. Borra todas las que digan 3.8.

Comment: para evitar esos problemas usa `pyenv`